# SEO friendly, non-www, hidden index.php URL

Tags: seo, no-www

I would like to do four things with apache mod_rewrite:

1. Remove www

   ```
   http://www.example.com/ >>> http://example.com/
   ```
2. Remove index.php

   ```
   http://example.com/index.php >>> http://example.com/
   ```
3. Rewrite URI

   ```
   http://example.com/index.php?rewrite=request >>> http://example.com/request
   ```
4. Remove the last slash

   ```
   http://example.com/request/ >>> http://example.com/request
   ```

I've read many examples but none of them worked properly.

**Edit:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?rewrite=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I using this right now, but it's not enough. Thanks

Comment: well , show us what you have tried and what did not work. Further more , you should really use a php router script for url rewriting. It would leave your apache config minimal and clean,and is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*)http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ http:// %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?rewrite=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ index\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:// www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

with apache mod_rewrite: